# menucool tooltip javascript purchase pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am pretty new to web design and programming. I am trying to learn as much as i can but i have issues with tool tip JavaScript that i used in my website

[Here is my website](http://cooking.comyr.com/)

Does anyone know how to disable the "purchase pop up box"?
[This is exactly what i am using](http://www.menucool.com/slider/slider-with-tooltip)

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Here is the JS script which is used in my image slider on my webpage

Comment: That said, the slider library you're using seems to be commercial. You have purchased the license, right? If so, the correct place to ask would be the vendor's customer support.

Comment: I havent purchased it yet. The JS is too long that i cannot put in here. Sorry about that. The purchase pop up appears randomly. In the JS script there is something that is trigering this but i am not well educated to debug the issue.

Comment: Well, I assume the popup goes away as soon as you have paid for it.

Answer (score 2):

For Latest `tooltip.JS`:

1. Find below js Code in tooltip.js

   `e.className = "mcTooltipInner";`
2. Now Find `e[P] = h;` code, next to upper searched code(in if condition) and replace below code with `e[P] = h;` code.

> ```
> $('.mcTooltipWrapper').css('display','none');    
>  /* e[P] = h; */
> ```

Comment: @csandreas1 finding is helpful to reach your destination code where we have to make a change. :)

Answer (score 1):

you just have to find and delete the script after `g=new ub;`  until  `var c=e(R,k);`, so find and delete the script:

```
if(a)console.log=a}if(E&&E.id=="mcttDummy"&&d.innerHTML.indexOf(X("kdvh#Uh"))!=-1)g.i=function(){};return g},jb=function(d,c,b){b=b||{};var a;for(a in c)d[a]=b[a]!==undefined?b[a]:c[a]},gb=0,I,tb=function(b){if(!b){b=e(o,"mcttDummy");if(!b){b=e(N,"div");b.id="mcttDummy";b[a].display="none";
```

and it won't show the pop-up again

Answer (score 0):

Open the **tooltip.js** in Notepad....

Do a search for "mcttDummy", this is the popup that comes up randomly.

You should see a function like this:

```
if(!b){
b=e(N,"div");
b.id="mcttDummy"
...etc...
}
```

In that condition where the object is not B,

Put an alert there, that's useful for debuging javascript.

```
if(!b){alert("mcttDummy");
b=e(N,"div");
b.id="mcttDummy"
...etc...
}
```

Now try to get the purchase popup to come up.
It should be triggered after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The tool script relevant portion i.e.

```
if(a)console.log=a}if(E&&E.id=="mcttDummy"&&d.innerHTML.indexOf(X("kdvh#Uh"))!=-1)g.i=function(){};return g},jb=function(d,c,b){b=b||{};var a;for(a in c)d[a]=b[a]!==undefined?b[a]:c[a]},gb=0,I,tb=function(b){if(!b){b=e(o,"mcttDummy");if(!b){b=e(N,"div");b.id="mcttDummy";b[a].display="none";
```

May also look like -

```
if(a)console.log=a}if(k&&k.id=="mcttDummy"&&d[P].indexOf(mb("kdvh#Uh"))!=-1)g.i=Nb;return g},yb=function(d,c,b){b=b||{};var a;for(a in c)d[a]=b[a]!==undefined?b[a]:c[a]},ub=0,M,Jb=function(b){if(!b){b=l(L,"mcttDummy");if(!b){b=l(N,"div");b.id="mcttDummy";b[a][Y]="none";
```

If you remove the complete script, the script may not function properly. Instead of that, you may simply replace "none" as "". This will solve the issue as I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this code in js-image-slider.js

```
for(var b=[],a=0;a<e[d];a++)b[b[d]]
```

Start this for loop from 24 i.e a=24
The logic is simple.... they iterate the for loop to 24 i.e making the string "slider purchase reminder" count to 24 including spaces.
If you iterate the loop from 24 the string making logic will not work, hence it will not be displayed on the page. So your code snippet should look like

```
for(var b=[],a=24;a<e[d];a++)b[b[d]]
```